# Multithreaded input with mutex not smooth (as expected)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, input

I am currently developing a 3D engine from scratch (again) as I wanted to use more modern techniques (and frankly, my previous design was crap). Now I am in the process of implementing my input thread.

Now that I am more experienced I know that if I write to the same variable from my input thread and my rendering/main thread then I will get data races so I decided to use mutexes(mutices?) to lock data that could be written to in different threads, but this is causing an unacceptable bug: mouse input isn't smooth any more :/

I did kind of expect that though, I just thought my thinking might be off.

Now I am stuck at a crossroads because I don't know how to go about fixing this issue!

The variable that I am writing to from both threads is `x_rel` and `y_rel` which is mouse position relative to last position when I received an event.

The input thread sets the variables and the rendering/main thread resets them to `0.0` when it is finished with them. This works fine, but as I said, this gives me very rigid mouse motion.

My question here is, what can I do to get smooth input while still being race safe across threads?

---

***Here is my mutex definition (it is global):***

```
std::mutex mouse_mutex;
```

---

***Here is the code that I use to get the mouse events:***

```
void input_thread_func(application &app, const bool &running, double &x_rel, double &y_rel){
    while(running){
        application::event ev = app.get_input();
        switch(ev.type){
            case events::mouse_motion :{
                if(mouse_mutex.try_lock()){
                    x_rel = ev.xrel;
                    y_rel = ev.yrel;
                    mouse_mutex.unlock();
                }
                break;
            }

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

***And here is my main function:***

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    /* all my init stuff */

    application app;
    bool running = true;
    double x_rel = 0.0, y_rel = 0.0;
    std::thread input_thread(
        input_thread_func,
        std::ref(app), std::cref(running)
        std::ref(x_rel), std::ref(y_rel)
    );

    double multiplier = /* whatever I like */;        

    while(running){
        /* check input data */

        if(mouse_mutex.try_lock()){
            update_camera(x_rel * multiplier, y_rel * multiplier);            
            app.set_mouse_pos(0, 0);
            x_rel = 0.0; y_rel = 0.0;
            mouse_mutex.unlock();
        }

        /* do rendering stuff */
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `try_lock()`?

Comment: @pmjordan so my `main` thread doesn't block rendering and so my input thread can get other input if it can't lock the mouse input mutex.

Comment: Have you measured what percentage of `try_lock()` calls at both sites actually succeeds, and have you measured how much the blocking version costs you? I have a sneaking suspicion this is where your problems are coming from. Letting a mutex block is normally not a bad thing, just hold it for the minimum time possible. (your mutex in main() could be released a lot sooner by pulling the update_camera call out of it)

Comment: @pmjordan it gives almost the same results, just slightly more rigid mouse motion. At the moment I am not using mutexes at all and I would really prefer to be safe against race conditions.

Comment: Instead of locking the mouse coordinates variables, why not use a flag (`std::atomic<bool>`) to tell the rendering thread that the coordinates have changed? This way you don't need to update the variables at both places. the rendering thread looks them up whenever the flag is set, does its business, and reset the flag afterwards. The event thread updates the variable and set the flag when a mouse event happens.

Comment: @didierc that gives absolutely terrible mouse movement :L I think it doesn't work because the values of `[x|y]_rel` are being written/read at the wrong times. (Setting a flag doesn't help with the data race in main when it modifies `[x|y]_rel` either)

Comment: what rendering backend are you using? OpenGL? How many threads will interact with the rendering thread through shared data?

Comment: How frequently does your `app.get_input();` return when running on a worker thread vs on the main thread? Depending on operating system, type of event handling, etc. you might find that events are handled on the main thread regardless, and that querying them from another thread just adds synchronisation overhead and queueing latency.

Comment: @didierc my rendering thread manages all of the data that will be rendered, I plan on using compute shaders for physics so that won't change either.

@pmjordan I actually can not do input in the main thread because for some unknown reason my xcb input loop lags to balls if I use `xcb_poll_for_event`. Because of that I'm using `xcb_wait_for_event` in it's own thread. That shouldn't be causing synchronization overhead anyway because if I don't use locks(mutexes) I get no input lag/rigidness whatsoever.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that most of the time the event thread is holding the lock: it keeps reacquiring the lock just after releasing it, since it doesn't do anything else. You could probably make things smoother by just having the event thread µsleep in between loops, and have the rendering thread hold the lock just enough time for it to copy the values over, as it's been suggested.

Comment: My 2 cents: this is hardly the case to shove in threads. Some APIs won't even allow meddling with system resources (rendering context, window messages, etc) from multiple threads. Do you really want rendering to be asynchronous? Don't you care about the rendering thread possibly missing updates from the game engine, thus never rendering certain frames? What about missing inputs? What if 2 mouse events come in before the rest of the system sees anything? I think the design is broken, this is not where you should use threads.

Comment: @DanielKO I'm pretty sure you misunderstand how I've implemented this. It's impossible that the rendering thread could "miss updates from the game" because pretty much everything happens in the rendering thread. I would be extremely surprised if a thread lost it's own data.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Imagine this scenario: I move the mouse 10 units to the right; `input_thread_func()` sees that and assigns `x_rel = 10`; but it also is quick enough to see that I moved 5 more units to the right, so it assigns `x_rel = 5`. Only now the rendering thread has a chance to try to lock it and see `x_rel = 5`. It reacts as if the mouse moved 5 units when I actually moved 15 units. If you think you are clever, and use `+=` instead of `=` to accumulate the relative movement, how do you apply that to a `left_button` boolean? You need synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

This is my understanding of your problem:

Basically, you have 2 threads, one dealing with mouse events coming from the system, and one taking care of rendering duties. As far as I understand, the later needs the most recent mouse position in order to compute an accurate set of camera matrices. However, because of the nature of the input device, the event thread is flooded with mouse position events: the system polls the device fast enough to get many updates per rendering frame, and these updates get pushed back to the event thread. That thread having only that task to do, it will constantly lock/unlock the mouse mutex while processing these events, and the odds of having that lock held by the event thread is high when the rendering thread actually wants to get ahold of it.

There are two possible problems coming out of your current setup:

- either the rendering thread needs *all* the mouse updates, and thus you'd need to implement an event queue between that thread and the event thread to keep track of all of them, then you'd be essentially filtering mouse events to dispatch them to rendering:

  1. setup a mouse event queue between those threads, and just push mouse events from the input queue to that new queue.
  2. have rendering check the mouse queue at each frame, and do as many camera updates as necessary, or better yet - as suggested in the comments, combine all these events in one single camera update, if possible. You should try putting that computation in the event thread, in order to reduce load on rendering.
- or rendering only needs the latest event (as it seems to be doing), in which case you need to update the mutexed data structure with the latest one only (thus reducing contention on that mutex).

To recap, depending on how the camera update function works wrt. mouse events, you will probably have to change it to work with only one set of absolute coordinates built cumulatively from all the relative events (maybe you can get them directly from the mouse event structure?), and only update the mutexed data *once* per event stream.

<sub>Note:

You may also check how other engines do it: the IdTech2 (Quake I/II) series of engines are monothreaded, but they're still a good source of inspiration. Each frame, these 
deal with all mouse inputs in one go. During a frame render, a first routine is called (`In_Move`,`HandleEvents`, or some other function, depending on the backend, see the sys_* files) to check all the events and update all the related structures. When the rendering code (`R_RenderFrame`) is invoked, there're no contention on these structures anymore. You probably want to "emulate" the same behaviour, by making sure that rendering isn't held back by one or more mutexes. A possible solution has been described above for mouse input, and can certainly be extended to handle other type of input devices.</sub>